# Why is my local DNS server reverse lookup showing 005.free-counter.co.uk?

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

For example, when using `nmap`:

```
Nmap scan report for 005.free-counter.co.uk (192.168.0.105)
Host is up (0.0031s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
53/tcp  open  domain
80/tcp  open  http
548/tcp open  afp
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:09:13:C6 (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
```

This Raspberry Pi is running `dnsmasq` as well as [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) but I don't quite understand why this is happening but I assume it has something to do with reverse lookup of the ip address to whatever domain is registered with that domain globally?

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.0.105` is an RFC 1918 reserved address, and as such it does not have a reverse lookup name. Where your name server got the name it gave you is impossible to say without knowing how that exact name server is configured.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what I can look into?